# Naming weights of a layer within a custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom layer within a Dense sublayer. I want to be able to name the weights of this sublayer. However, using `name="my_dense"` on the sublayer initializer doesn't seem to do this; the weights simply get named after the outer custom layer.

To illustrate the problem, suppose I want a custom layer that simply stacks two dense layers. I'll print the names of the weights of this custom layer.

```
class DoubleDense(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    self.dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(units, name="first_dense")
    self.dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(units, name="second_dense")
    super(DoubleDense, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.dense1.build(input_shape)
    self.dense2.build(self.dense1.units)

  def call(self, input):
    hidden = self.dense1(input)
    return self.dense2(hidden)

dd = DoubleDense(3)

# We need to evaluate the layer once to build the weights
trivial_input = tf.ones((1,10))
output = dd(trivial_input)

# Print the names of all variables in the DoubleDense layer
print([weight.name for weight in dd.weights])
```

The output is this:

```
['double_dense_1/kernel:0',
 'double_dense_1/bias:0',
 'double_dense_1/kernel:0',
 'double_dense_1/bias:0']
```

...but I was expecting something more like this:

```
['double_dense_1/first_dense_1/kernel:0',
 'double_dense_1/first_dense_1/bias:0',
 'double_dense_1/second_dense_1/kernel:0',
 'double_dense_1/second_dense_1/bias:0']
```

So, Keras has named these weights ambiguously; there is no way to tell whether a weight tensor belongs to `dd.dense1` or `dd.dense2` by its name alone. I realise I could select the layer first and *then* the weights (`dd.dense1.weights`), but I would prefer not to do this in my application.

Is there a way to name the weights of a sublayer of a custom layer?

Comment: Not sure this is satisfactory, but you can create a function that takes an input, calls two dense layers and return the output. This is not a sublayer, but you can still use it as a block when building models.

Comment: Indeed, that would work for this example. But my actual custom layer is an RNN cell, so this would not work in that case, unfourtunately.

Comment: What if you try to make it a `Model` instead of a layer? (A `Model` is also a `Layer`, so it will probably work as a cell)

Comment: Making the cell a subclass of `keras.Model` instead of `keras.layers.Layer` throws `ValueError: Weights for model rnn_cell have not yet been created.`. I'm not sure why. I've tried building the cell by calling `.build(input_shape)` explicitly but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: One more update, in case anybody is having the same issue. This bug, which (seemingly) unavoidably leads to two variables getting assigned the same name, causes more issues down the line. In particular, the model saving functions `.save` and `.save_model` don't work anymore (they seem to require variable names to be unique) and throw the error `RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)`. I still don't have any answers. I'll raise this issue on Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the name for the subclass layers you need to include `name_scope` and then call `build` for each layer.

Below is the modified code which will give names for each layer in the output.

```
class DoubleDense(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    self.dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(units)
    super(DoubleDense, self).__init__( **kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    with tf.name_scope("first_dense"):
      self.dense1.build(input_shape)
    with tf.name_scope("second_dense"):
      self.dense2.build(self.dense1.units)

  def call(self, input):
    hidden = self.dense1(input)
    return self.dense2(hidden)


dd = DoubleDense(3)


# We need to evaluate the layer once to build the weights
trivial_input = tf.ones((1,10))
output = dd(trivial_input)

# Print the names of all variables in the DoubleDense layer
print([weight.name for weight in dd.weights])
```

**Output:**

```
['double_dense/first_dense/kernel:0', 'double_dense/first_dense/bias:0', 'double_dense/second_dense/kernel:0', 'double_dense/second_dense/bias:0']
```

Hope this answers your question, Happy Learning!

Comment: @Isaac Breen - If you think I have answered your question, please upvote and accept the answer.